# How to escape the required login or protection ensured by the middleware in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

A Django web application usually has login required, however there is a url or view that does not need to have a login_required. How to make it work?

Comment: Isn't that the default behaviour unless you are using some middleware? Don't you have to explicitly mark anything with login required as so, either via decorator or inheritance?

Comment: @RobertKearns Yes, it has a middleware to authenticate the application, however, there is a view that doesn't need to have it.

Comment: What middleware are you using?

Comment: It's 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', and     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',

Comment: That is just default middleware, what views are you trying to access that are protected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is mentioned by Django Documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt, that looks the correct solution.

**Utilities**

The examples below assume you are using function-based views. If you are working with class-based views, you can refer to Decorating class-based views.

**`csrf_exempt(view)`**

This decorator marks a view as being exempt from the protection ensured by the middleware. Example:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

Answer (score 0):

re_path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('about/',views.about,name="about"),

By default all the admin urls are login protected and if you do not use admin site and if you do not use any login_required decorator in views.py then that url will not be login required just like the "about/" url here.